# Google Chrome saving PDF files generated by PHP with a .php extension

Tags: tcpdf

When I generate a PDF using PHP in Google Chrome, it opens fine. As soon as I try to save the PDF file, it tries to save it as a .php file.

It works fine in FireFox and Safari. Is it a Google Chrome issue or is there something I can do in PHP to make it work properly?

I'm using TCPDF to generate the PDF files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can work arround it unless you can figure out how to rename the file with a PDF extension. Even then Chrome's PDF viewer's *save as* may redownload the file regardless, so that's something you may need to consider.

Comment: Is there any way to maybe force download instead?

Comment: Yep: just set the appropriate headers (see http://www.ryboe.com/tutorials/php-headers-force-download for an example).